# Spring Cloud Config Server spams "Adding property source" during health check [Spring Boot 2.6+]?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

For a Spring Cloud Config Server project, we recently migrated from Spring Boot `2.1.8.RELEASE` to `2.6.6`. However, the application seemed to be flooded with below logs that eventually leads to k8s pod crashing/restarting. And the INFO log is generated each time `/actuator/health` from kube-probe is called.

> 2022-08-30 19:20:19.182  INFO [config-server,5bd83ee81e7d3ccb,e17a13026d9c85ee] 1 --- [nio-8888-exec-5] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: Config resource 'file [{spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir}/application.yml]' via location 'file:{spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir}'
> 2022-08-30 19:20:19.543  INFO [config-server,7557d9d04d71f6c7,a3d5954fe6ebbab1] 1 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: Config resource 'file [{spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir}/application.yml]' via location 'file:{spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir}'
> ...

Note that I have replaced the actual file path to config repo in the container with `spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir`.

Is there something that we missed on how Spring Cloud Config Server behaves differently since the update? Or how to disable health check endpoint to add a property source? As [EnvironmentController.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/main/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/environment/EnvironmentController.java) seems to be the culprit.

Comment: I have a same issue. Have you ever fixed it? Here is my link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75277601/spring-boot-microservices-config-server-cannot-fetch-property-file-adding-pro